# How to pass custom options to a Symfony form

Tags: php, symfony

I've to pass a custom option to a symfony form. I followed the documentation setp by step but my options will not pass.

The FormType

```php
class AdvertType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $entityManager = $options['em'];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {    
        $resolver->setRequired(array(
            'em',
        ));

        $resolver->setAllowedTypes(array(
            'em' => 'Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'advert';
    }
}
```

Here is the Code from the controller.

```php
$form = $this->createForm(new AdvertType(), new Advert(), array(
    'em' => $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(),
));
```

Symfony will throw an exception that my option `em` is missing.

> Exception: The required option "em" is missing.

I followed the tutorial to add a data transformers: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

I cleared my cache and restarted my web server but nothing will work. What did I wrong? Did I missed a configuration to pass my `$options`? It looks like the `$options` array from the controller I passed will never reach the `buildForm` method.

I'm using Symfony v2.3.5. For testing I updated to the latest (2.3.6) but the problem still exists.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used my form twice (in different ways) so the error results from the wrong usage. I looked on the wrong place for the error. The code in general is correct. Sorry for that.

Comment: Ugh, I hate it when this happens! Haha.

Answer (score 3):

I've copied your code and used it successfully (Symfony 2.3.6). It worked! You shouldn't have to clear your cache. So I'm not sure what's wrong. You should also consider adding the `data_class` option in your resolver if you want to constrain the form to your Advert object, e.g.

```
    $resolver
        ->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Your\Bundle\Entity\Advert',
        ))
    ;
```